# Write duplicate numbers down the page in numerical order. (Image may make more sense.)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Sorry if this is a basic question, still trying to learn. Is there any way I can have duplicate numerical numbers going down the page. Rather than having to manually type each number down twice, I was wondering if there is a `formula/tool` where I could drag down.

Thank you for your time and help.

***Example:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a number in A1, put =A1 in the A2 and then =A2+1 in A3. Then select A2-A3 and drag down.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the start number in the first cell (say, 1). Enter the formula below in the cell underneath it.

```
=A2+MOD(ROW()+MOD(ROW(A$2)-1,2),2)
```

Replace both references to *A2* with the address of the cell in which you wrote the start number. Press Ctl+C (Copy).

On the Ribbon's Home tab click *Find & Select* > Go To ...  In the *Reference* field enter the range you want to copy to (presuming that it's a large range that takes too long to select). and press OK. That selects the target range. Press *Enter* to complete the pasting.

Answer (score 0):

In cell `A1` enter this formula and then copy down as far as you need...

```
=ROUND(ROW()/2,)
```

Comment: Conciseness is valued.